# How "java.util.Comparator.compare(String o1, String o2) " method works

Tags: java, compare, comparator

Can anyone please explain me how java "compare" method works for the input `"XXXXS, XXXS, XXS, XS,S,M, L,XL,XXL,3XL"`

If the input is `"3XL,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL"` output is `"3XL,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL"` but I want to make the output as `"XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL"`

According to the java documentation [("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) it says 
"Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

When the input is two Strings how it compares as less than or greater than?I think the output is not based on alphabetical order because "3XL,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL" is the output I got.

Comment: Read the documention. It'd have been faster than to post this question... If there is something in particular that you don't get _in the doc_, then say so.

Comment: `Comparator` is an *interface*. It doesn't implement anything. That is for you to do. Have you done so? If yes, show us what you have. If not, then you are asking us to implement it for you, but this site is not a code writing service, so that is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String`s are comparable in a lexicographic order (i.e., the order they'd appear in a dictionary). If you want to implement a `Comparator` for clothes  sizes, you'd have to write the logic yourself. E.g.:

```
public class ClothesSizeComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private static final List<String> SIZES = 
        Arrays.asList("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "3XL");

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int s1pos = SIZES.indexOf(s1);
        int s2pos = SIZES.indexOf(s2);
        return Integer.compare(s1pos, s2pos);
    }
}
```

Note: This `Comparator` assumes that both strings represent valid clothe sizes. If this assumption can't be made, you'd have to add some error handling.

Comment: Hi Mureinik, Thanks for the information. I found this issue in "hybris" implementation. They have developed the above logic. But the issue was an error in their logic. They consider "3XL, 4XL" as a number & ignore the normal order we specified("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "3XL"). That was the issue. I fixed that issue, then it is working fine. Thanks